# RXTX 2.2pre2 crash using inside AWT/Swing

Tags: java, swing, crash, jvm, rxtx

I'm using rxtx library for connecting to a serial port.
For that I set up a gui using different tabs.
The first tab shows the available devices calling gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers() on rxtx library version 2.2pre2 (os is lastest stable ubuntu linux 32 bit).

Doing this on start works perfectly. But if I switch to another tab and back again the list should be updated (called from the stateChanged fucntion of the StateChange interface for the tab). If I'm doing that the jvm crashes. I also tried to use rxtx 2.1.7 but still the same problem.

Any idea why this happens?

Error-Log:
Current thread (0x823c8800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=5578, stack(0x8220d000,0x8225e000)]

```
siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00002a0a

Registers:
EAX=0x8206890c, EBX=0x001a9684, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x8225b96c, EBP=0x8225ba38, ESI=0x8225ba90, EDI=0x823c8800
EIP=0x00002a0a, EFLAGS=0x00210286, CR2=0x00002a0a

Top of Stack: (sp=0x8225b96c)
0x8225b96c:   001a5a4d 823c8928 8225ba90 00000000
0x8225b97c:   823c8800 018fdff4 823c8800 8206890c
0x8225b98c:   013bedcc 8225b9b8 82c1a43c 00000001
0x8225b99c:   82c1a43c 8225b9bc 00000001 018fdff4
0x8225b9ac:   823c8800 00000000 850c8ed0 01362bcd
0x8225b9bc:   018fdff4 823c8800 823c8800 8225ba58
0x8225b9cc:   013911bc 850c0360 00000010 00000001
0x8225b9dc:   823c8800 018fdff4 8225c3e4 823c2768 

Instructions: (pc=0x00002a0a)
0x000029ea:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x8206890c is an unknown value
EBX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

Stack: [0x8220d000,0x8225e000],  sp=0x8225b96c,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00002a0a
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.testRead(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z+0
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.registerValidPorts([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V+202
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.registerScannedPorts(I)V+1416
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.initialize()V+42
j  gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()Ljava/util/Enumeration;+57
j  de.hanneseilers.jftdiserial.core.connectors.RXTXConnector.getAvailableDevices()Ljava/util/List;+8
j  de.hanneseilers.jftdiserial.core.FTDISerial.getAvailableDevices()Ljava/util/List;+11
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.updateDevicesModel()V+26
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.access$0(Lde/northernstars/mr/botcontrol/core/tabsections/TabSectionSettings;)V+1
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings$1.itemStateChanged(Ljava/awt/event/ItemEvent;)V+56
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Ljava/awt/event/ItemEvent;)V+35
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged()V+64
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ListDataEvent;)V+28
j  javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Ljava/lang/Object;II)V+65
j  javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+38
j  javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+55
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.updateLibsModel()V+41
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.stateChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ChangeEvent;)V+21
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged()V+186
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ChangeEvent;)V+4
j  javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged()V+57
j  javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(I)V+14
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(IZ)V+97
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(I)V+13
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+77
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+54
j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23
j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
j  java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+18
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+581
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+327
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+126
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+12
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+19
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x49118f]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x57f

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.testRead(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z+0
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.registerValidPorts([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V+202
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.registerScannedPorts(I)V+1416
j  gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.initialize()V+42
j  gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()Ljava/util/Enumeration;+57
j  de.hanneseilers.jftdiserial.core.connectors.RXTXConnector.getAvailableDevices()Ljava/util/List;+8
j  de.hanneseilers.jftdiserial.core.FTDISerial.getAvailableDevices()Ljava/util/List;+11
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.updateDevicesModel()V+26
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.access$0(Lde/northernstars/mr/botcontrol/core/tabsections/TabSectionSettings;)V+1
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings$1.itemStateChanged(Ljava/awt/event/ItemEvent;)V+56
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Ljava/awt/event/ItemEvent;)V+35
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged()V+64
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ListDataEvent;)V+28
j  javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Ljava/lang/Object;II)V+65
j  javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+38
j  javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+55
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.updateLibsModel()V+41
j  de.northernstars.mr.botcontrol.core.tabsections.TabSectionSettings.stateChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ChangeEvent;)V+21
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged()V+186
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ChangeEvent;)V+4
j  javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged()V+57
j  javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(I)V+14
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(IZ)V+97
j  javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(I)V+13
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+77
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+54
j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23
j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
j  java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+18
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+581
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+327
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+126
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+12
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+19
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+73
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V+245
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x82056000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5579, stack(0x81faf000,0x82000000)]
  0xb7507c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=5564, stack(0xb76de000,0xb772f000)]
=>0x823c8800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=5578, stack(0x8220d000,0x8225e000)]
  0x823c7400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5577, stack(0x8225e000,0x822af000)]
  0x823c5c00 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5576, stack(0x822af000,0x82300000)]
  0x823b3400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5575, stack(0x82607000,0x82658000)]
  0x82c2b800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5573, stack(0x826d9000,0x8272a000)]
  0x82c29c00 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5572, stack(0x8272a000,0x827ab000)]
  0x82c27800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5571, stack(0x827ab000,0x8282c000)]
  0x82c26000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5570, stack(0x8282c000,0x8287d000)]
  0x82c14400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5569, stack(0x82baf000,0x82c00000)]
  0x82c12c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5568, stack(0x82d25000,0x82d76000)]

Other Threads:
  0x82c10400 VMThread [stack: 0x84b24000,0x84ba5000] [id=5567]
  0x82c2d400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x82658000,0x826d9000] [id=5574]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
```

The rxtx is used in jFTDIserial (https://github.com/hanneseilers/jFTDIserial) a self-build java library for connecting to serial ports through several other libraries. The jFTDIserial works perfectly in standalone test.

Comment: Maybe it's important, that this problem occurs on linux only. Windows 64 bit is working. Link to source code: https://github.com/NorthernStars/MR-Botcontrol/blob/master/mrBotControl/src/de/northernstars/mr/botcontrol/core/tabsections/TabSectionSettings.java

Answer (score 0):

The error was a problem with overwriting native library for rxtx from second instance of jFTDiserial library.